# How do I organize products from newest to oldest?

Tags: product-list, products-management, products, products-view

My products are showing in a random order. I would like to correct this to display products from the most recently added to oldest products.  Is this possible?

Comment: Where are they showing in random order?

Comment: In each product category, they are not displayed with the newest product first.  For example, here is our "Bottoms" category: http://eccentricsboutique.com/clothing/bottoms.html?limit=30

As you can see, the "new" products are just scattered in the products that are no longer new. Is there a way to specify in Magento that we want products displayed with "new" first to oldest?

Answer (score 2):

Against each category within magento you can set to sort order to be displayed. Name, Price etc. In order to configure this you need to load the admin section of the site. From the top navigation Catalog -> Manage Categories. Select the category you want to manage and select display options. From there you can modify what order the products should be displayed in.